Upgrading npm failed
C:\Users\BJP>npm install -g npm@latest
npm error code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm error Invalid URL


npm error A complete log of this run can be found in:
C:\Users\BJP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-09T17_47_25_977Z-debug-0.log


How to clear this error?

This issue is usually caused by a configuration problem or an NPM request failure.
To check the current registry, run:
npm config get registry
If the URL https://registry.npmjs.org/ is correct, ensure it is not blocked by proxies.
You can also try this:
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
npm config --global rm proxy
npm config --global rm https-proxy
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"

